# Is it possible to stop and return

Tags: r, bash

I have run into this problem a few times recently. I have some R code whereby if a certain thing happens, I want to `stop()` and exit the function, therefore returning an exit code. However I also want to `return()` the latest copy of an object from within the function which is created in that function.

Is this possible?

As a really silly example, see the below code. Wherever you see a `stop()` I would also like to `return()` the value of `i`. NOTE: I know this isn't how you would write this function. It's simply an example

```r
tmp <- function() {
  i <- 1
  if (i == 3) {
    stop()
  }
  i <- i + 1
  if (i == 3) {
    stop()
  }
  i <- i + 1
  if (i == 3) {
    stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `tryCatch?`

Comment: What you want is not `stop`, but rather a `browser()` which stops the code and allows you to inspect all the objects.

Comment: I don't want to inspect the objects, I want to actually return them for use in the next step

Comment: Then `tryCatch`.

Comment: After your edit: why don't you just `return(i)`? You can always do that. You can also return an object that tells the parent function that an error condition occurred.

Comment: Because I need to return an error for use on the command line. And there is no parent function. I simply want to see the value of `i` at the point of failure.

Comment: So you have 3 stop cases that can fail.  Then set `stop_case <- case`, (1, 2, 3)  If the rbind object is a dataframe, (df) then just return stop_case and df as a list.  i.e., `retList <- list(stop_case, df)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use rlang's `abort` to return additional data with an error object:

```r
library(rlang)

## dummy function
fun <- function(x, error = FALSE) {
  x <- x + 1
  if(error)
    abort("Error!", x = x)
  return(x)
}

## no error
fun(1, error = FALSE)
#> [1] 2

## error 
fun(2, error = TRUE)
#> Error!

## display last error
last_error()
#> <error>
#> message: Error!
#> class:   `rlang_error`
#> backtrace:
#>  1. global::fun(2, error = TRUE)
#> Call `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full backtrace

last_error()$x
#> [1] 3
```